Every phone I connect to my pc charges only - I can't use it to transfer data
I am new on Ubuntu 23.10.4 and I am having a problem with connecting my Tecno Spark 20 smartphone on my pc while my phone works clearly on other computers. I don't know where the problem is?

Maybe this link can help you find a solution.

Does this answer your question? How do I connect my android smartphone to my PC through USB and transfer files?

Phones are not dumb storage devices. They are fully-featured computers that can pretend to be dumb storage devices when you so instruct them to behave that way. This seems like a question about your phone settings more than a question about Ubuntu.
